# Binary Search Tree Nothing Getting Printed

Tags: c, recursion, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to create an unbalanced Binary Search Tree from a given input as a sequence of (unsorted) integers.
My approach has been to recursively find the right place for each individual node and then allocate memory for it and define the data for it. 
But I'm unable to debug the program effectively as despite having scrutinized it properly,I can't seem to identify the problem. For an input as follows:

```
11
15 6 4 8 5 3 1 10 13 2 11
```

The Expected output should have been the post-order and in-order traversals,but strangely nothing is getting printed(Except for the newline I've given in between).

**NOTE:** This question is closely linked to the BST related question that I previously asked,but the approach is entirely different and so is the challenges I'm facing. Hence think twice before going for my neck and probably closing down the topic.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define arrmax 100
/***Pointer-based BST implementation, developed by Abhineet Saxena***/


/***The data-type declaration***/
typedef struct node{
int data;
struct node* parent;
struct node* leftChild;
struct node* rightChild;
}Node;

typedef struct tree
{
    Node* root;
    int size;
}BSTree;

/***Method prototypes***/
/*Method to create a tree*/
Node* createTree(int[],int,int);
void insert(Node*,int);

Node* createNode(int);
void inOrder(Node* root);
void postOrder(Node *root);

int main(void) {

    BSTree* bs_tree;
    bs_tree=malloc(sizeof(BSTree));
    bs_tree->root=NULL;
    bs_tree->size=0;
    /****Taking the input****/
    int num_elem,iterv;
    scanf("%d\n",&num_elem);
    int *arr=malloc(sizeof(int)*(num_elem));
    for(iterv=0;iterv<num_elem;iterv++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&arr[iterv]);
    }
    bs_tree->root=createTree(arr,0,num_elem-1);
    postOrder(bs_tree->root);

    printf("\n");
    inOrder(bs_tree->root);

    return 0;
}
Node* createTree(int marr[],int left,int right)
{
    int iterv;
    Node* root;
    root=NULL;
//  Node** root_ptr;
    //*root_ptr=root;
    for(iterv=left;iterv<=right;iterv++)
    {

        insert(root,marr[iterv]);

    }
    return root;
}
Node* createNode(int key)
{
        Node* tree_node;
        tree_node=malloc(sizeof(Node));
        //printf("Used malloc here for key: %d\n",key);
        tree_node->data=key;
        tree_node->leftChild=NULL;
        tree_node->rightChild=NULL;
        tree_node->parent=NULL;
        return tree_node;
}
void insert(Node* root,int key)
{
        if(root==NULL)
    {
        root=createNode(key);
        //return root;
    }
    else if(root->leftChild!=NULL && root->rightChild!=NULL)
        {
            if(key<root->data)

                        insert(root->leftChild,key);
                        else

                       insert(root->rightChild,key);
        }
        else if(root->leftChild!=NULL && root->rightChild==NULL)
        {
            if(key>root->data)
            {
                Node* tnode=createNode(key);
                root->rightChild=tnode;
                tnode->parent=root;
                return;
            }
            else if(key<root->data)
                insert(root->leftChild,key);

        }
        else if(root->leftChild==NULL && root->rightChild!=NULL)
        {
            if(key<root->data)
            {
                Node* tnode=createNode(key);
                root->leftChild=tnode;
                tnode->parent=root;
                return;
            }
            else if(key>root->data)
                insert(root->rightChild,key);
        }
        else
        {
            if(key<root->data)
            {
                Node* tnode=createNode(key);
                root->leftChild=tnode;
                tnode->parent=root;
                return;
            }
            else if(key>root->data)
            {
                Node* tnode=createNode(key);
                root->rightChild=tnode;
                tnode->parent=root;
                return;
            }
        }

}

void inOrder(Node* bst_tree)
{
    if(bst_tree!=NULL)
    {
        inOrder(bst_tree->leftChild);
        printf("%d ",bst_tree->data);
        inOrder(bst_tree->rightChild);
    }
    else
        return;
}
void postOrder(Node* bst_tree)
{
    if(bst_tree!=NULL)
    {
        postOrder(bst_tree->leftChild);
        postOrder(bst_tree->rightChild);
        printf("%d ",bst_tree->data);
    }
    else
        return;
}
```

Comment: What happened when root itself is NULL during call of insert(root,key) ?

Comment: The node you allocate and assign to `root` is never sent out of `insert()`. C is pass-by-value; `root = ....` does nothing to the *caller's* `root`. Thus `insert(root,marr[iterv]);` ultimately does nothing to `root` in `createTree`, and leaks memory while doing it. This problem is replicated with literally every invoke of `insert()` in this code, of which I count 5.

Comment: Then it will simply create the first node, as I've specified at the very beginning of the insert() function.

Comment: The calls to `insert()` are doing nothing. You need to return the node from `insert()` back to the caller.

Comment: @WhozCraig ,so what changes should I make in this case?

Comment: Exactly what Filipe said. Return the modified (or not) root back to the caller. Either pass the pointer by address (pointer to pointer) or utilize the return value of the function (which currently returns void). There are *plenty* of examples of this done right on this site if you look hard enough.

Comment: If I return the root to the caller(i.e. createTree), it will only return the immediate predecessor right? But I intend to return the pointer to the root node of the entire tree,how do you suppose should I do that? And thank you all so much by the way for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this one: in createTree, you set root to NULL and then call

```
insert(root, marr[iterv]);
```

...and now magically expect root to be non-NULL after it. You need to change to this calling convention:

```
insert(&root, marr[iterv]);
```

...and change the signature of insert to void insert(Node**,int);

Then, in the insert function, instead of root you use *root, and instead of root->something you use (*root)->something. I tested your program with these changes and it works.

An additional nitpick: integer ranges should be left-inclusive and right-exclusive so you should call createTree in this way:

```
bs_tree->root=createTree(arr,0,num_elem);
```

and then have this loop:

```
for(iterv=left;iterv<right;iterv++)
```

Then the length of the range is right-left which is more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #define arrmax 100
    /***Pointer-based BST implementation, developed by Abhineet Saxena***/


    /***The data-type declaration***/
    typedef struct node{
    int data;
    struct node* parent;
    struct node* leftChild;
    struct node* rightChild;
    }Node;

    typedef struct tree
    {
        Node* root;
        int size;
    }BSTree;

    /***Method prototypes***/
    /*Method to create a tree*/
    Node* createTree(int[],int);
    void insert(Node*,int);
    Node* createNode(int);
    void inOrder(Node* root);
    void postOrder(Node *root);

    int main(void) {

        BSTree* bs_tree;
        bs_tree=(BSTree*)malloc(sizeof(BSTree));
        bs_tree->root=NULL;
        bs_tree->size=0;
        /****Taking the input****/
        int num_elem,iterv=0;
        printf("Enter Number of Elements\n");
        scanf("%d\n",&num_elem);
        int *arr=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*num_elem);
        for(;iterv<num_elem;iterv++){
            printf("Enter keys\n");
            scanf("%d",&arr[iterv]);
        }
        bs_tree->root=createTree(arr,num_elem-1);
        postOrder(bs_tree->root);

        printf("\n");
        inOrder(bs_tree->root);
        return 0;
    }
    Node* createTree(int marr[],int right){
        Node* root =createNode(marr[0]);
        int iterv=1;
        for( ;iterv<=right;iterv++){
            insert(root,marr[iterv]);
        }
        return root;
    }
    Node* createNode(int key){
            Node* tree_node;
            tree_node=(Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
            tree_node->data=key;
            tree_node->leftChild=NULL;
            tree_node->rightChild=NULL;
            tree_node->parent=NULL;
            return tree_node;
    }
    void insert(Node* root,int key){
            if(root->leftChild!=NULL && root->rightChild!=NULL){
                if(key<root->data)
                    insert(root->leftChild,key);
                else
                   insert(root->rightChild,key);
            }
            else if(root->leftChild!=NULL && root->rightChild==NULL){
                if(key>root->data){
                    Node* tnode=createNode(key);
                    root->rightChild=tnode;
                    tnode->parent=root;
                    return;
                }
                else if(key<root->data)
                    insert(root->leftChild,key);
            }
            else if(root->leftChild==NULL && root->rightChild!=NULL){
                if(key<root->data){
                    Node* tnode=createNode(key);
                    root->leftChild=tnode;
                    tnode->parent=root;
                }
                else if(key>root->data)
                    insert(root->rightChild,key);
            }
            else{
                if(key<root->data){
                    Node* tnode=createNode(key);
                    root->leftChild=tnode;
                    tnode->parent=root;
                    return;
                }
                else if(key>root->data){
                    Node* tnode=createNode(key);
                    root->rightChild=tnode;
                    tnode->parent=root;
                    return;
                }
            }
    }
    void inOrder(Node* bst_tree){
        if(bst_tree!=NULL){
            inOrder(bst_tree->leftChild);
            printf("%d ",bst_tree->data);
            inOrder(bst_tree->rightChild);
        }
        else
            return;
    }
    void postOrder(Node* bst_tree)
    {
        if(bst_tree!=NULL)
        {
            postOrder(bst_tree->leftChild);
            postOrder(bst_tree->rightChild);
            printf("%d ",bst_tree->data);
        }
        else
            return;
    }
```

//Check this code is working .

Comment: Yes,its working perfectly fine :-) albeit one thing to remember, since you might be more adapted to C++ I believe, in C,initializations within for loop are not allowed. So instead of for(int iterv=0;...) , it should be: int iterv; for(iterv=0;...)

Comment: Actually i converted this code into c++ using `new` then i rollback to `malloc` .

Comment: @Abhin33t_S if it works then you should acc as answer or make comment this is how SO works.